# MVC Angular JS - $get calling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have $get calling un my C#- MVC - Angular Js Proj .
The url for request is incorrect for me and routing to the root proj folder on computer

```
   $http.get('../Home/GetResponse').success(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

How I should write the url given that the my controller name is 'HomeController' and the function is 'GetResponse' ?

Thanks .

Comment: Hi !! It's ok . i replace html file to cshtml and run it from proj - no by file ..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $http.get('Home/GetResponse').success(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

Comment: It's not working . I get url : file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/MyProj/MyProj/Views/Home/~/Home/GetResponse

Comment: $http.get('Home/GetResponse').success(function (response) {
                alert(response);
            });

Comment: no good . file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/MyProj/MyProj/‌​Views/Home/Home/GetResponse

Answer (score 0):

By using $http.get your are making a http request. This request can only be handled by a web server.

You should be hosting your asp.net MVC website in IIS and your $http.get should use an address along the lines of

`http://localhost/Home/GetResponse`

Right now you are trying to make an http request to a file on your file system which will not work. It would expect to find a folder called Home and a file called GetResponse.

Only IIS is able to load the http modules that can translate the route (in this case /Home/GetResponse) to an action on a controller.

Comment: In this case I will get access denied because it is cross domain calling fom JS .

Comment: Is your angularjs code part of the same mvc website? If it is you should also load the web page via a web server and not the file system. You may also use visual studio's built in web server. This can be configured by editing the properties of your Web project. Be aware that the port used by visual studio's server will not be the default of 80.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. Do make sure you mark the correct answer to help others that may have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get(baseurl+'Home/GetResponse').success(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

just add baseurl in the layout page as

var baseurl=@Url.Content("~/");